Nested Array and Filter Sorting formula to combine and aggregate into most frequent list
Working on formating a sheet where I need to pull normalized data into an analytics page. The criteria is to pull from one tab to the next.
Get data using B & E and then apply the values to preset grouping and find the total count.
Output should be formatted for the 5 timeframes for 7/14/30/60/90 days. Such as:
7 Days:  1M (7)
14 Days: 100M+ (2)
30 Days: 50-75M (3)
60 Days: 10-20M (8)
90 Days: 3-10M (9)

I've been trying with this formula in this sheet but up against a wall so figure I'd see if anyone has a more elegant solution than where I'm at now?
Helper sheet
Here's my logic behind what I'm doing so far:

Categorize data from F column into the grouping sets with ArrayFormula and If statements to normalize the data into the needed format to find frequency.
Filter for each timeframe and count occurances for 7 Days / 14 Days / 30 Days / 60 Days / 90 Days.
Combine results and display data.

I am trying to push this together with a single cell formula but I'm not getting the results needed.
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(
  categories, {"1M", "1-3M", "3-10M", "10-20M", "20-30M", "30-50M", "50-75M", "75M-100M", "100M+"},
  timeframes, {7, 14, 30, 60, 90},
  labels, {"7 Days", "14 Days", "30 Days", "60 Days", "90 Days"},
  result, MAP(timeframes, labels, LAMBDA(days, label,
    LET(
      filtered, FILTER(Parabolic!F2:F, (Parabolic!B2:B >= TODAY()-days) * (Parabolic!F2:F <> "")),
      categoryCounts, COUNTIFS(filtered, categories),
      mostFrequentIndex, MATCH(MAX(categoryCounts), categoryCounts, 0),
      mostFrequentCategory, INDEX(categories, mostFrequentIndex),
      countMostFrequent, MAX(categoryCounts),
      label & " " & mostFrequentCategory & " (" & countMostFrequent & ")"
    )
  )),
  TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, result)

SOLUTION: I was able to work out a solution, albeit not sure it's really that elegant. Functional but somewhat clunky. If anyone has a better approach I'd really enjoy seeing another way.

Can you clarify what this means:  7 Days: 1M (7) 14 Days: 100M+ (2) 30 Days: 50-75M (3) 60 Days: 10-20M (8) 90 Days: 3-10M (9)  Is this a count or something? How do you derive 7 Days: 1M (7) from your sample spreadsheet data? Simplify it down in your question with some small sample data (a few rows and columns) your calculation and expected result.

It's what's needed on the final output. So the formula will first take the data thats in the E column and group/round that data based on the grouping parameters then identify the time period in B column and find the frequency that repeats the most.
Output will be based on last 7 days / 14 days / 30 days ect...

That doesn't clarify. Please read the last part of my comment if you need help.

Dataset is in columns B for the date and time of occurance which is correlated to price in Column F within the Paraolic tab. For instance here are the first 10 rows of data:
7/11/24 - 4:00 AM    $27,970,000
7/11/24 - 9:45 AM    $1,000,000
7/11/24 - 8:30 AM    $10,320,000
7/11/24 - 7:00 AM    $69,290,000
7/10/24 - 4:12 AM    $320,000
7/10/24 - 6:55 AM    $6,920,000
7/10/24 - 7:30 AM    $27,970,000
7/10/24 - 7:30 AM    $6,810,000
7/10/24 - 8:00 AM    $870,000
7/9/24 - 4:25 PM    $2,100,000
7/9/24 - 4:20 PM    $2,810,000

The formula needs to first classify the price column within the determined price group and then count the freqency how many times that occured in the historical past based on the range of those days.
Output should be in this format in the Analytics tab where a single cell formula is applied:
"7 Days 1M (7)
14 Days 100M+ (2)
30 Days 50-75M (3)
60 Days  10-20M (8)
90 Days 3-10M (9)"

You're restating what you've shared in Q and link, not clarifying. To get assistance, [edit] the question with a minimal amount of sample data, the desired result, and the necessary steps.  For example, for the single result 7 Days 1M (7) explain: a) 7 days? eg. All values in B >= TODAY()-7 or >=MAX(B:B)-7 or [your_logic]. b) 1M? eg. Values in F >=$1M or  [your_logic] c) (7)? Row count where both a) and b) are TRUE or [your_logic].  Remember, comments request clarification but relevant details should an [edit] to question not in comments

Updated question and structure...

Yes. I reviewed your comments, your question edis and your spreadsheet and I still have no idea how you get from your sample data to  7 Days 1M (7)

Last 7 days of data to be from data set to get the frequency of the data where Column B (date & time) and dollar value (column f).
Then will need the last 14 days and so on so forth.

I tried that but my results from your data didn't match what you got.

Check out the helper columns I put in the 2nd tab. The steps are all outlined there. The problem I have is the step of combining into a single cell formula. I'm kind of stuck at this point in getting it there without the helper columns which I can't use for the project.
What aren't you getting? I don't understant?

=LET(dates,Parabolic!B2:B, amts,Parabolic!F2:F,
   lookupTable,A2:B10, groups,{7,14,30,60,90}, 
   JOIN(CHAR(10),
     MAP(groups, 
       LAMBDA(g, RIGHT(CHAR(8199)&g,2)& " Days ⯈ "& JOIN(", ",
         BYROW(
           SORTN(
             QUERY(
               FILTER(
                 VLOOKUP(amts/10^6, lookupTable, 2, 1),
                   dates>TODAY()-g),
               "Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) Group By Col1
                Label COUNT(Col1) ''"),1,1,2,0),
           LAMBDA(r, JOIN(" (", r)& ")")))))))


If you want to have 0-1M include 1M, and 1M-3M include 3M, (and so on) then subtract a penny from all the amts variables using:
VLOOKUP((amts-.01)/10^6,... 

Instead of:
VLOOKUP(amts/10^6,...


The formula uses a VLOOKUP and a range reference to a Lookup Table in A2:B10 which could alternatively be hardcoded

Lookup Table




A
B
                                                                                                                                                            




1
 Lookup 
    Table    



2
0
1M



3
1
1-3M



4
3
3-10M



5
10
10-20M



6
20
20-30M



7
30
30-50M



8
50
50-75M



9
75
75-100M



10
100
100M+





Hardcoded
To hardcode a lookup array use
lookupTable,
  {0,"1M"; 1,"1-3M"; 3,"3-10M"; 10,"10-20M"; 20,"20-30M";
  30,"30-50M"; 50,"50-75M"; 75,"75-100M"; 100,"100M+"}

Instead of
lookupTable,A2:B





Examples are shown in your workbook (blindspots_sheet)

    =ARRAYFORMULA(LET(
  categorize, LAMBDA(f, 
    IF(f <= 1000000, "1M",
      IF(f <= 3000000, "1-3M",
        IF(f <= 5000000, "3-5M",
          IF(f <= 10000000, "5-10M",
            IF(f <= 20000000, "10-20M",
              IF(f <= 30000000, "20-30M",
                IF(f <= 50000000, "30-50M",
                  IF(f <= 75000000, "50-75M",
                    IF(f <= 100000000, "75M-100M", "100M+")
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  getData, LAMBDA(days, QUERY(
    FILTER(
      HSTACK(
        TEXT(Parabolic!$B$2:B, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"), 
        categorize(Parabolic!$F$2:F)
      ), 
      Parabolic!$B$2:B >= TODAY() - days
    ), 
    "SELECT Col2, COUNT(Col1) 
     WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL 
     AND Col2 IS NOT NULL 
     GROUP BY Col2 
     ORDER BY COUNT(Col1) DESC 
     LIMIT 1 
     LABEL COUNT(Col1) '' 
     FORMAT COUNT(Col1) '""(""0"")""'", 
    0 
  )),
  data7, getData(7),
  data14, getData(14),
  data30, getData(30),
  data60, getData(60),
  data90, getData(90),
  formatResult, LAMBDA(result, IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(result)), result, REGEXREPLACE(result, "\(\((.*)\)\)", "($1)"))),
  results, {
    "7 Days " & formatResult(INDEX(data7, 1, 1) & " (" & INDEX(data7, 1, 2) & ")"), 
    "14 Days " & formatResult(INDEX(data14, 1, 1) & " (" & INDEX(data14, 1, 2) & ")"), 
    "30 Days " & formatResult(INDEX(data30, 1, 1) & " (" & INDEX(data30, 1, 2) & ")"), 
    "60 Days " & formatResult(INDEX(data60, 1, 1) & " (" & INDEX(data60, 1, 2) & ")"), 
    "90 Days " & formatResult(INDEX(data90, 1, 1) & " (" & INDEX(data90, 1, 2) & ")")
  },
  TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), TRUE, results)
))

